# Does Joda-Time `DateTime` class have methods such as setHours()/setMinutes() as is available in Javascript Date object

Tags: datetime, time, jodatime

I would like to set hours/minutes/seconds manually in `DateTime` class from Joda-Time library. What I am trying to do is keep year/month/day value but discard hours/minutes/seconds from date object.

```
DateTime today = new DateTime();
today.??? (method to call set hours/minutes/seconds to 0)
```

Happy new year to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Immutable Objects

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) uses [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) by default. Rather than call a setter method to change (“mutate”) a member variable, we call a method to generate a new instance based largely on the original.

## `withTime`

To create a new DateTime with a certain time-of-day, call the [`withTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTime-int-int-int-int-) method.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
DateTime lunchtimeToday = now.withTime( 12, 30, 0, 0 ); // Half-past noon.
```

## First Moment Of The Day

If you want midnight (first moment of the day), call `withTimeAtStartOfDay`. Usually this is `00:00:00.000` but not always.

```
DateTime todayStart = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

## Time Zone Is Crucial

Note that time zone is crucial to determining when a day starts. 'Today' in Paris starts sooner than it does in Montréal.

If you omit the time zone, your JVM’s current default time zone will be applied automatically. Better to specify than rely implicitly on this default.

Use [proper time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes that are neither standardized not unique.